# How to setup a common storage for kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

i have a `container a` with only files required for my app which is on other `container b` and `container c`. I want the files in `container a` to be accessible by `container b` and `container c`. Its kind of like `container a` has to be a `fileserver`. I am not sure how can i go about doing this, should i install `samba` server in `container a` and make it accessible by other containers or is there any other smart way of doing it. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe your environment in a bit more details? Is the cluster hosted in cloud or locally?

Answer (score 0):

Choose a shared storage, external to the container, that supports [persistent volumes in access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) ReadOnlyMany. Possibly ReadWriteMany, if the container requires it.

For example: NFS, gluster, ceph.

Comment: Is it not possible to use one container as a file server? which will only have `readonly` files

Comment: Do whatever you like in containers, but Kubernetes provides volumes so you don't need a file server in a container. Or even care if it is NFS or Ceph, at the pod level, as that is abstracted.